# Deleted the default web site in IIS 6.0 and now it won't work?

Tags: iis

I stupidly deleted the default website in IIS 6.0 and now when I add a new website and try to browse to it I get a 404?

I tried re-installing IIS but still no joy.

Comment: Did you specify a proper document root?

Comment: @ Marc B - I'm not sure. How do I specify a document root?

Comment: It should be in the IIS control panel for the site's configuration. Pretty much every site has to have a document root.